# breeze error: Cannot read property 'toODataFragment'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have the following BreezeController

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<MyContext> _ContextProvider = new EFContextProvider<MyContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _ContextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    ....other controllers exposing model types....

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Size> Sizes()
    {
        return _ContextProvider.Context.Sizes;
    }
}
```

which I access from the client from my DataContext.js with this

```
var getSizes = function (sizesObservable, modelId) {
        var query = entityQuery.from('Sizes').where('ID', '==', modelId)
            .orderBy('sortOrder').orderBy('size').orderBy('enteredDate');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (sizesObservable) {
                var intialValues = { size: ' Select a Size', sizeID: breeze.core.getUuid(), modelID: modelId };
                createNullo(entityNames.size, 'Size', intialValues);
                sizesObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Sizes] from remote data source', data, false);
        }
    };
```

All of this works just fine.  I would like to add another route to my controller that has some specialized filtering done on the server.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Size> GetUniqueSizes()
{
    return //custom filtering logic here.
}
```

with the following javascript in my DataContext.js

```
var getUniqueSizes = function (sizesObservable, modelId) {
        var query = entityQuery.from('GetUniqueSizes').where('modelID', '==', modelId).where('Approved', '==', 'True')
            .orderBy('sortOrder').orderBy('size').orderBy('enteredDate');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (sizesObservable) {
                var intialValues = { size: ' Select a Size', sizeID: breeze.core.getUuid(), modelID: modelId };
                createNullo(entityNames.size, 'Size', intialValues);
                sizesObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('Retrieved [Sizes] from remote data source', data, false);
        }
    };
```

but when I do this I get the following error on the client

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toODataFragment' …localhost:63144/scripts/breeze.debug.js:12728:23)
```

Why is this route not working?

Comment: does the error occur before or after the request hits the server?

Comment: Before it hits the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the multiple orderBy statements to a [multiple property sort](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#MultiplePropertyOrdering).

```
.orderBy('sortOrder,size,enteredDate')
```

likewise, you might have better luck if you [combine the where clauses](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#CompositeWhere).

Comment: Can you explain how you got to this from that error message?

Comment: lucky guess- had a hunch that .orderby(...).orderBy(...) didn't work